# Thickness of bars in a histogram

Tags: histograms

How can I control the thickness of the bars (here vertical lines) in a `Histogram` plot? For example in the plot below (of the corresponding image: http://goo.gl/RyMpXE) I can hardly see histogram bars above 300 brightness.

Code for producing the histogram:

```
imageData = Flatten[ImageData[image, "Bit16"]];

Histogram[imageData, {0, 2500, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log", PlotRange -> {{0, 2500}, {All, 10^6}}, 
  ImageSize -> 2000, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
    FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"# of Pixels", ""}, {"Brightness", ""}}];
```

**I would like to use in my case a bin width of 1. Since one brightness value occurs above 2000 I want to be able to see the corresponding bar - which is too thin**.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the thickness of the bars be imposed by the binning you are using? I think you might have to use wider bins to get wider bars. Or perhaps use higher-contrast colors, or a non-white background. Can you show us the code that generated your graph?

Comment: Adding `Background -> Black` makes for a more visible line ([picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7xxp3.png)), although of course it does not change the width of the bin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Histogram generates `Rectangle` objects as bars whose edges are set to be transparent. In your case the rectangles are so thin that you can thicken them simply by drawing their edges. This will apply to all bins though!

```
yourhistogram = Histogram[imageData, {0, 2500, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
  (* Note the modified plot range! the original one clipped the highest bars for me *)
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2500}, All}, 
  ImageSize -> 2000, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"# of Pixels", ""}, {"Brightness", ""}}];

yourhistogram /. 
   EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.]]] -> EdgeForm[{Orange, Opacity[1], Thickness[0.003]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @mrz You are very welcome! Thank you for the accept as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Histogram[{x1,x2,x3...},bspec]`, where bspec is bin width specification.

**Simple example:**

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
Histogram[data, 5]
```

**Output:**

[image: output with bin specification]

Alternatively, you could changethe presentation to see the bins better:

**Simple example:**

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3, 1/2], 500];
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 1/3], 500];

Histogram[{data1, data2, data3}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

**Output:**
[image: output version2]

Or using `PlotTheme`

**Simple Example:**

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
Histogram[data, 5 , PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

**Output:**

[image: output version 3]

**Reference:**

[Histogram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)

Comment: I know that - my question is different ... see added information in bold above  ...

Comment: @mrz the width of the bin to which you referred to as thickness is governed by the bin specification. If you insist on keeping it at 1, the only ways known to me how to make the bins more visible are specified above. I do apologise if it didn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your help ... may be I was a little bit unclear. Sometimes an answer which does not exactly solves my question helps for an other problem. So I am always happy for each response.